# Nautilus menu icons missing in Ubuntu 16.10 (GTK 3.20)

Tags: nautilus, configuration, gtk3

I upgraded to ubuntu 16.10 a few days ago, and suddenly my menu icons in nautilus are missing again. I checked the dconf setting (org.gnome.desktop.interface.menu-have-icons) and it is still true. Maybe the location of that setting has been moved. Or there is some other problem.

Has anyone else this problem or an idea how to solve it?

[image: nautilus-context-menu]

The entries "Update", "Commit", "Push" from RabbitVCS are supposed to have icons.

Answer (score 1):

`gtk-menu-images` and `gtk-button-images` [have been deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-menu-images.%20Also%20check) and maybe are being ignored.

[This link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/) may be of help to you. And I transcribe the post contents here:

> (I've already posted in http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1680581#post1680581 , re-posting here for users not subscribed there):
>
> Both gtk-menu-image and gtk-button-images were deprecated and ignored, after that they made them deprecated but not ignored: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=627a03683f5f41efbfc86cc0f10e1b7c11e9bb25 https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=c46aca463a9d66cf402ec8c3f9f2e2efc98c42ca
>
> the problem is the gsettings keys (org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons and menus-have-icons) are gone so I don't see a way to set them...
>
> However it seems you can set the relevant GtkSettings via the gnome-settings-daemon xsettings plguin: open dconf-editor -> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings and change the overrides key from:
>
> {}
>   to:
>
> {'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}
>   usually the change is instantaneous (e.g. in gimp), but some apps need to be restarted (e.g. firefox).
>
> Or just use gsettings:
>
> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
>   but note that this method overwrites the current value of that key; one obvious caveat is if you've previously enabled pasting with the middle click from gnome-tweak-tool -> "keyboard and mouse", you'll need to re-set it there again (unlike the above gsettings command, gnome-tweak-tool "adds" new values to the overrides key and doesn't blindly overwrite it).
>
> Edit: testing recently, it seems now that toggling either of these settings in gnome-tweak-tool remove the custom values added above:
>
> Top Bar -> "show application menu"
>   Keyboard and mouse -> middle-click paste so if you toggle any of those settings you'll have to re-add the 'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1> bits.

Comment: That doesn't work on GTK 3.22.8

Comment: I can second that; the override "gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}" is ignored.