# Nautilus Contextual Menu Icons Gone After Upgrade to 17.04

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, icons, 17.04

I just upgraded to 17.04 from 16.04 via the two-step. The upgraded Nautilus, version 3.20.4, does not appear to have the option to display icons in the contextual menus -- as explained and demonstrated [in this post](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ubuntu-unity-menu-button-have-icons/).

I looked in `Dconf Editor`, and `org.gnome.desktop.` no longer has an `interface` option.  That is where the icons were surfaced in previous versions.

[Here is a similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556997/context-menu-icons-in-nautilus-3-10-1) that shows the problem for another version of Nautilus, but the sole proposed solution didn't work.

Does anyone know how to get the contextual menus back?  `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool` is close to my favorite tool, and custom icons make my experience more fluid and efficient.

Comment: Look here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/836858/nautilus-menu-icons-missing-in-ubuntu-16-10-gtk-3-20 Though even if it worked your just slightly forestalling the inevitable. Likely in 17.10/18.04 gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

### Temporary solution by downgrade

I am not sure how to fix it in 3.20.4, but what you can do is to try and downgrade to version of Nautilus that is used in Ubuntu 16.04 until newer 
versions become more stable.

What worked for me, is:

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager (`synaptic-pkexec` from terminal)
2. Settings -> Repositories
3. Other software tab -> Add...
4. Paste repository **`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main`**
   This should add repository for official Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.
5. Make sure "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'Xenial Xerus' is checked and close "Software & Updates" window, going back to Synaptic PM.
6. Press "Search", type "nautilus", choose "name" search criteria, Search.
7. Select "nautilus" package by left-click, after which go to "Package -> Force Version" in top main menu of SPM, select 1:3.18.4 Xenial and accept it.
8. It will ask to mark package "nautilus-data" as well, do so and Apply changes.
9. After SPM installed version 3.18, select "nautilus" again and check "Package -> Lock Version" in menu.
10. Now go to "Settings -> Repositories" again and uncheck Ubuntu 16.04 repository, to avoid issues with it later.

I can not guarantee that this will work for you because I am not using Gnome, but it can be possible temporary solution for you until someone with knowledge can let us know what the actual core issue is.